# Biblatex's alphabetic style with numbers instead of years

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

By default, when you choose `style=alphabetic` with biblatex, citations will take the form [Abc12]. I would like to have only the letters – e.g. [Abc] – unless there is an ambiguity, in which case it should be numbered, e.g. [Abc1], [Abc2], etc.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246718/35864 help?

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's the answer. I suggest marking my question as a duplicate (instead of deleting it), so that others find their way more easily to the solution.