# Alphabetic biblatex style. Cites without year number

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` with `style=alphabetic`. Cites appears then as [Knu89]. But I would like them to appear as [Knu], without the last two year numbers. How can I do this? Also, if there are several entries in my bib file with same author (for example, two different entries with Donald Knuth as the author), I would like them to appear as [Knu1] and [Knu2]. How could this be achieved?

I've been looking here through previous questions on TeX Stack Exchange and I have found nothing related.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246718/35864 looks like it would be the answer

Answer (score 0):

Moewe has located the answer in [tex.stackexchange.com/q/246718/35864](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246718/35864). I could not find that post before.